# Passing Pointer to Pointer to functions

Tags: c, pointers

```
void foo(double **A, double **B) {
    //....   
}

int main() {  
    double **A;
    double B[10][10];
    int i, j;

    A = (double **)malloc(sizeof(double*) * 10);        

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        *(A+i) = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * 10);
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            *(*(A+i)+j) = i * j;
        }
    }

    foo(A, B);

    return 0;
}
```

This gives me a warning

```
warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'double [10][10]' to parameter of type 'double **'
  [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

From my understanding B holds a pointer to a pointer of type double. Am I not doing the same thing with A and B. Why am I getting this warning only for B?

Comment: "From my understanding B holds a pointer to a pointer of type double" - actually `B` is an array. See how there are no `*` symbols in its declaration. Arrays and pointers are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary difference between passing a *pointer to array* and *pointer to pointer* from a syntax standpoint isn't too difficult to understand. When you pass a pointer to array, either `array[x][y]` or `(*array)[y]`, you specify the parameter as either:

```
somefunc (type array[][y])
```

or

```
somefunc (type (*array)[y])
```

The rule to take away -- when passing a pointer to array, you must always pass the number of columns involved.

On the other hand, when passing a *pointer-to-pointer-to-type*, you only need to pass a pointer. e.g.:

```
somefunc (type **array)
```

The primary difference in "*Why?*" has to do with how the information is stored in memory. Take for example `int array[x][y]`. There you have `x * y` integers stored in a sequential block of memory. `x` and `y` provide a direct index to an integer within that sequential block. (anywhere within the `x` arrays containing `y` values each).

On the other hand, with `int **array`, you have a pointer to pointer -- meaning that your `array[x]` value identifies points to another pointer holding the beginning address of an array of `y` values. There is no requirement that any of the separate pointers identified by `array[0]`, `array[1]`, `...` be stored in any sequential manner.

Take the following example. You have `array` (your typical `array[x][y]` or 2D array as it is often referred to) and `arraydp` an array of *pointer-to-pointer-to-type* (your typical *double-pointer*). The example shows the different way you must handle passing each.

The tweak in the game is that a function can only return a single value (a pointer), so to return a reference to `array[x][y]` it must be returned as a double-pointer and recast appropriately.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 5

/* function prototypes */
int **alloc_fill (size_t n);
int **alloc_fill_dp (size_t n);
void prn_array (int (*a)[MAX], size_t nrow);
void prn_array_dp (int **a, size_t nrow, size_t ncol);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int (*array)[MAX] = { NULL };   /* pointer to array of MAX ints */
    int **arraydp = NULL;           /* pointer to pointer to int    */
    size_t i, n;

    n = argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 5;   /* set number of rows */

    /* fill 'n' pointer to array[MAX] */
    array   = (int (*)[MAX])alloc_fill (n);

    /* fill 'n' pointer to pointer to int */
    arraydp = alloc_fill_dp (n);

    if (!array || !arraydp ) { /* validate both allocated */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: alloc_fill failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("\n elements of '%zu' arrays:\n\n", n);
    prn_array (array, n);
    printf ("\n elements of '%zu' arrays:\n\n", n);
    prn_array_dp (arraydp, n, MAX);

    free (array);           /* single call to free for 'array' */

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) /* free each pointer, then arraydp */
        free (arraydp[i]);
    free (arraydp);

    return 0;
}

/* allocate/fill 'n' pointer to array of MAX int */
   int **alloc_fill (size_t n)
{
    int (*a)[MAX] = { NULL };
    size_t i, j;

    if (!(a = calloc (n, sizeof **a * MAX))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
            a[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);

    return (int **)a;
}

/* allocate/fill 'n' pointer to pointer to type int */
   int **alloc_fill_dp (size_t n)
{
    int **a = NULL;
    size_t i, j;

    /* allocate 'n' pointers */
    if (!(a = calloc (n, sizeof *a))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        /* allocate MAX ints */
        if (!(a[i] = calloc (MAX, sizeof **a))) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
            return NULL;
        }
        for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
            a[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);
    }

    return a;
}

/* print function for 'nrow' pointers
 * to array of 'MAX' ints
 */
void prn_array (int (*a)[MAX], size_t nrow)
{
    size_t i,j;

    for (i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
            printf (" %4d", a[i][j]);
        // putchar ('\n');
        putchar ('\n'), putchar ('\n');
    }
}

/* printf function for 'nrow' pointers
 * to pointer to 'ncol' ints
 */
void prn_array_dp (int **a, size_t nrow, size_t ncol)
{
    size_t i,j;

    for (i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < ncol; j++)
            printf (" %4d", a[i][j]);
        // putchar ('\n');
        putchar ('\n'), putchar ('\n');
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_ptr_to_array

 elements of '5' arrays:

    1    2    3    4    5

    2    4    6    8   10

    3    6    9   12   15

    4    8   12   16   20

    5   10   15   20   25


 elements of '5' arrays:

    1    2    3    4    5

    2    4    6    8   10

    3    6    9   12   15

    4    8   12   16   20

    5   10   15   20   25
```

**Difference of Storage in Memory**

Here in memory is where the rubber meets the road. I you look below, you have the debugger (`gdb`) depiction of the memory layout for both `array` and `arraydp`. Notice with `array` all values are sequential. However, with `arraydp`, the first `5` values are the pointer address that point to each of the respective `5 int` arrays that make up the values for `arraydp`. If you then examine pointer address for `arraydp[0-4]`, you then may index each of the individual values:

`array` in memory:

```
(gdb) x/25d array
0x603010:       1       2       3       4
0x603020:       5       2       4       6
0x603030:       8       10      3       6
0x603040:       9       12      15      4
0x603050:       8       12      16      20
0x603060:       5       10      15      20
0x603070:       25
```

`arraydp` in memory:

```
(gdb) x/49d arraydp
0x603080:       6303920 0       6303952 0
0x603090:       6303984 0       6304016 0
0x6030a0:       6304048 0       33      0
0x6030b0:       1       2       3       4
0x6030c0:       5       0       33      0
0x6030d0:       2       4       6       8
0x6030e0:       10      0       33      0
0x6030f0:       3       6       9       12
0x603100:       15      0       33      0
0x603110:       4       8       12      16
0x603120:       20      0       33      0
0x603130:       5       10      15      20
0x603140:       25

(gdb) x/5d 6303920
0x6030b0:       1       2       3       4
0x6030c0:       5

(gdb) x/5d 6303952
0x6030d0:       2       4       6       8
0x6030e0:       10

(gdb) x/5d 6303984
0x6030f0:       3       6       9       12
0x603100:       15

(gdb) x/5d 6304016
0x603110:       4       8       12      16
0x603120:       20

(gdb) x/5d 6304048
0x603130:       5       10      15      20
0x603140:       25
```

From a programming standpoint, the differences may seem subtle, but they are critical from a syntax standpoint. Look it over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 2):

`B` is an array of arrays of 10 `double`, a very different type from an array of pointers to arrays of `double`.  Change `foo`'s prototype to:

```
void foo(double **A, double (*B)[10])
```

Also simplify the code in `main` this way:

```
int main() {
    double **A;
    double B[10][10];
    int i, j;

    A = malloc(10 * sizeof(*A));
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        A[i] = malloc(10 * sizeof(*A[i]));
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            A[i][j] = i * j;
        }
    }
    foo(A, B);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof` is not a function.  `sizeof *A` and `sizeof *A[i]`  You still get a vote.

Comment: @synthetel: `sizeof` is indeed an operator and parentheses could be elided for an expression operand, but I prefer to always parenthesize the operand for consistency. I particularly dislike this syntax: `malloc(10 * sizeof * A[i])`, not to mention its ugly sibling: `malloc(sizeof * A[i] * 10)`

Comment: Ok.  But `malloc(n * sizeof *A[i])` and `malloc(sizeof *A[i] * n)` and `malloc(n * (sizeof *A[i]))` and `malloc((sizeof *A[i]) * n)`

Comment: These do not appeal to me any more than `malloc(n * sizeof*A[i])` or `malloc(sizeof*A[i] * n)`.  I am quite anal about style.  I like to have the function style syntax for `sizeof` for consistency with `countof` too.

Comment: @synthetel Do you really prefer `(sizeof thing)` to `sizeof(thing)`?

Comment: chqrlie: Perhaps you'd also enjoy `return(0)`  immibis: Only because it helps to educate people about `sizeof` being different than functions and macros.  Lots of people have no idea and using `sizeof(` _x_ `)` keeps perpetuating that.

Comment: @synthetel: please stay civil, `return` is not an operator, it is a statement. I understand your point and your intent, I have a different view on the subject. Consistency is not so obvious: why can we write `malloc(sizeof a)` and not `malloc(sizeof int)`?  The latter is not ambiguous.  `sizeof` is not a real operator, it is a syntactic curiosity with many quirks as can be seen in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803572/what-is-sizeof2-5-equal-to

Comment: chqrlie: It was meant to be a civil comment.  `return(x)` has a distinct advantage over `return x` regarding macros used for debugging.  Style-wise, in your `for (`, the space indicates something to distinguish `for` from a function.  In `sizeof (int)`, we do the same.  Your `countof` argument is the strongest, in my opinion.  Anyway, I'm sure we both recognize that we're probably regurgitating an ancient debate.  You have my respect.

Comment: @synthetel: And you have mine. But regarding debugging macros, they would look like `RETURN(x);` or `check_return(x);`, redefining the `return` keyword as a macro for this purpose might be legal but so unpleasant...

Comment: @chqrlie `sizeof` with an expression is certainly a real operator.  There's nothing strange in the question you linked to. `sizeof(type)` is a bit of a quirk.

Comment: @M.M: it is a very special kind of operator even for the expression operand as the operand is not evaluated. `sizeof(type)` definitely has quirks, eg: `sizeof(char[rand()])` where `rand()` **is** evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Try `void foo(double **A, double B[10][10])`  then pass it `foo(A, B)`