# What is sizeof(2.5) equal to?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, sizeof

An examination question was:

> Q2: `sizeof(2.5)` is equal to ____.
>
> A.1
>
> B.2
>
> C.3
>
> D.4

There are no such suffixes as `f l F L`, so floating-point constant `(2.5)` has a double type. Since nothing else is specified, I suppose its value is unspecified. For example, on some implementations whose `CHAR_BIT` is 32(causing `sizeof (char)==sizeof (long)`, maybe), the answer can be B.

However, in most cases, where `CHAR_BIT` is 8, the answer should be 8, but 8 isn't listed on the paper!

When asked such a ridiculous question in a exam/interview, what should I answer?

PS: Just ignore these useless parentheses please :)
PPS: Is IEEE 754 granted by the standard?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow deals with broken code, not broken interviewers.

Comment: @Quentin yeah, a good teacher/interviewer should not give his/her students/interviewees this question.

Comment: The question could be nice (you need to know what `sizeof` is, that it works with expressions, and what type the literal `2.5` is). The answer, however, cannot be determined without additional information.

Comment: It's a bad interview question, but I think the crux of what OP is asking, is "what is the result of sizeof(2.5)?".  That question is on topic, yet probably a duplicate.

Comment: I agree with @TrevorHickey, this question is on topic.  An better but equally tricky question would be *What is the value of `sizeof('2')`?*

Comment: @chqrlie equal to sizeof (int), I suppose

Comment: @sunqingyao: correct for the C language, but not for its elated cousin C++.  Character literals have type `char` in C++, hence `sizeof('2')` evaluates to `1` in C++.

Comment: @chqrlie Interesting......

Comment: Maybe it's a trick question and you're supposed to explain that probably none of the answers is right

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question is inconsistent: `sizeof(2.5)` is implementation defined. Without extra context, one cannot determine which answer to choose.

If this is an oral examination, you can explain this to the examiner and should get a very good mark given how much you already know.  (btw IEEE-754 is **not** mandated by the Standard, but a very common implementation of `double`).

If it is a written exam for which you cannot give further explanation (the marginal space being too exiguous), you should select `4` for the following reasons:

- the examiner might erroneously assume `2.5` to be a `float`, and also erroneously assumes `float` to always be 32 bits, further erroneously assuming bytes to be 8 bits.  This is the most probable explanation.  Be careful in a oral exam to stay humble if you think you know better than the examiner, it is probably the case here.
- the question might be misspelt, such as `sizeof("2.5")` but missing the `"`.  For this question, the answer is definitely `4`, and it would make sense to try and fool the student with the `C` answer.
- the question might be misspelt, such as `sizeof('2.5')` but missing the `'`.  For this **very** ugly question, the answer is the same as `sizeof(int)`, often  `4` on systems with 8 bit bytes. Note that `sizeof(2,5)` is also the same as `sizeof(int)`, but that would be a trick question too.
- on some DSP systems where `double` is 64 bits and `char` 16 bits, answer `4` would be correct.
- other answers are even less likely to be correct, except of course on the `DS9K` computer.

Comment: Why sizeof("2.5") will **definitely** yield 4? Shouldn't it be 4 on a 32-bit operating system, and 8 on a 64-bit operating system?

Comment: @sunqingyao: no, `"2.5"` is a string literal with 4 `char`s: `2`, `.`, `5` **and** `\0`, thus exactly `4` bytes, regardless of byte size.

Comment: Oh, I thought "2.5" is a char * instead of char[]. Thank you for teaching me something new today. Accepted.

Comment: `"2.5"` acts as a literal array.  `sizeof("2.5"+0)` would evaluate to `sizeof(char*)` because arrays decay as pointers if used as operands in an expression or as function arguments or return values.

Comment: Then I suppose questions such as "tell me the value yielded by sizeof ("2.5"), sizeof('2.5'), sizeof("2.5"+1), sizeof (&"2.5"), sizeof(&"2.5"+1) "will be nice

Comment: @sunqingyao:  All but the first are implementation defined.  This one is cute too: `sizeof("2.5"-"2.5")` and this one is another C++ oddity: `sizeof(NULL)`

Comment: Aha, is it equal to `sizeof (int)` ? Because arrays are decay as pointers, resulting integer constant 0?

Comment: No, `sizeof("2.5"-"2.5")` evaluates to `sizeof(ptrdiff_t)` and `sizeof(NULL)` may evaluate to `sizeof(void*)` or `sizeof(int)` or possibly `sizeof(long)` or `sizeof(long long)` depending on the actual definition of `NULL`, but hopefully the same value.

Comment: What a nice question!

Comment: note that 32-bit double is not permitted by the C standard  (there are minimum precision requirements that can't be satisfied by only 32 bits)

Comment: I added another explanation, which I believe is the most probable one for this bogus question.

Comment: I added another variant: `sizeof(2,5)` where  `(2,5)` is a comma expression equivalent to `5`. Hence `sizeof(2,5)` evaluates to `sizeof(int)` whose value is implementation defined.  Combining with string literals, you can study `sizeof("""")`, `sizeof("" "")`, `sizeof(" "" ")`, `sizeof(","",")` and `sizeof("","")`.  The first 2 evaluate to `1`, the next 2 to `3` and the last has an implementation defined value, since the second `""` decays into a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(2.5)` will yield the size of a `double` in bytes-- which is implementation defined.

**From the standard:**

> **5.3.3 Sizeof**
>   The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operand.
>   The result of sizeof
>   applied to any other fundamental type (3.9.1) is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` returns the size in `chars`, not bits. So, for example, `sizeof(char)` is by definition `1`.

However, this question is not very well written since it is system specific. My **guess** is that the `sizeof` of a `double` on your system is `8`, which would be 64-bit since `(8 * CHAR_BIT)` == `` (assuming the common value of `CHAR_BIT` as `8`).

Comment: As M.M correctly commented, 32 bit `double` would not be conformant with the C Standard.  If `sizeof(double)` is indeed `4`, you either have a non conformant system or `CHAR_BIT` must be greater than `8` (not necessarily 16, but close).

Comment: @chqrlie, looks like gcc and clang both use an 8 byte double according to this (64-bit compile):

https://godbolt.org/g/a3NjsS

So good call, I'll adjust my answer :-)